Disappearing Rows When Moving on Checked
I recently found some code someone posted on their website which moves items back and forth between sheets depending on if one of the columns in the row is checked or not. I just changed a couple of things, like the reference to the checked column and the number of columns.
I don't know much about writing this Apps Script code. I tried burying my head in it, but I'm lost. I understand the issue is that it's trying to grab a row that doesn't exist. Or at least that is what I think the issue is. However, sometimes when I add the checkmark to a row that's in the middle, it moves the row and the row touching it (I don't remember if it's the one above or below). Sometimes the row completely disappears and doesn't move to the other sheet. Sometimes it moves to the other sheet, but has no checkmark in it, when the items in that sheet without a checkmark should be moved back to the main sheet. It's weird.
Below are the errors I'm getting and below that is the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

function onEdit() {

  var mainSheet = "To Do";
  var sheetToMoveTheRow = "Completed";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  if(sheet.getName() == "To Do" && range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getValue() == true) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);}
  
  else if(sheet.getName() == "Completed" && range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getValue() == false) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("To Do");
    const aVals = targetSheet.getRange(1,1,targetSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    const targetRow = aVals.filter(String).length + 1;
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow , 1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    sheet.deleteRow(row);}
    
}


I tried changing some of the variables inside the code. Sorry, I don't know the proper terminology. I changed the values in a couple different getRange calls, but had no luck.

The included code uses a reserved function name for a simple trigger, onEdit. However, the screenshot shows part or an email message of errors on installable triggers. From this, it's clear that you have set an installable trigger to call this function; this causes the function to run twice and might be part of the problem.
First, you should decide if you want this function to be called by a simple or installable trigger. If you will use the simple trigger, then delete the installable trigger. If you decide to go the other way, change the function name and update the installable trigger accordingly.

Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure which way is easier; I'm not familiar with the two types of triggers.
I changed the name of the function to moveChecked but it is giving me an error with lines 3 and 4. It says mainsheet and sheettomovetherow are unused declarations.
What steps should I perform to get the code to either a simple or installable trigger? I'm very novice to this.
I greatly appreciate your help.

@GrisCasey Well, You are on your way to get familiar with Google Apps Script and th types of triggers. The second party of your comment is a follow up question so it should be posted  as a new question. Includes the textual error message as text, not as images and the lines referred by it.
